# InteliJ - How to create shortcuts for code samples

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using InteliJ and really love using it. One of the questions I have is this:

Is there a way to create code short cuts?

For instance, while bug testing, I am forever writing:

```
<?php die(var_dump($var)); ?>
```

and figured it would be great to have a shortcut key to automate this. i.e.

```
"Cmd Option D"
```

or something similar to dump the pre-defined statement into my code...

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Live Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-templates.html):

To define a template go to *Settings/Live templates*, then select group or create new group of templates and hit the green plus button and select *Live Template*.

In the abbreviation field type for example `vd` which will be the trigger for your snippet, define context, which represents the languages this template will be available for and put this in the *Template Text* field:

```
<?php die(var_dump($SELECTION$)); ?>
```

The `$SELECTION$` part is a [variable](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/live-template-variables.html) which represents current selection.

Now when you are in editor, you can just type `vd` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>. That will expand your snippet and put your cursor inside `var_dump()`.

You can event type the variable name you want to dump, select it, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, which will show you a *Surround with* dialog, where you can choose your template. After you select it your variable name will be surrounded with the `var_dump` snippet.

Another way to invoke a live template is to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> which will show you autocomplete popup with the available templates.

[image: Settings screenshot]